# Arrays with elements less or equal to the elements in given array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the most JS-style way to solve the following problem?

Given an array A, find all arrays B, such that for i <= A.length: B[i] <= A[i]. Example of what I expect:

```
#Input
A = [1,2,0]
#Output
B = [[0,0,0],
     [1,0,0],
     [1,1,0],
     [1,2,0],
     [0,1,0],
     [0,2,0]]
```

In Python I used:

```
B = [[]]; 
for t in [range(e+1) for e in A]:
    B = [x+[y] for x in B for y in t]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution. I'm sure it can be coded in a much nicer way. However, it works and I hope you find it useful

```
all_combinations(A){
    var B = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < A[0] + 1; i++) {
        B.push([i]);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
        var _tmp_array = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < A[i] + 1; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < B.length; k++) {
                var _new_element = B[k].concat([j]);
                _tmp_array.push(_new_element);
            }
        }
        B = _tmp_array;
    }

    return B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code (any loop for one item of the array `a`):

```
var a = [1, 2, 0], b = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a[0]; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < a[1]; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k <= a[2]; k++) {
      b.push([i, j, k]);
    }
  }
}
```

If you know the numebr of items in the array `a` only on runtime, use the following recursive function:

```
function fillArray(source, dest, recursionLevel, tempArr) {
  if (recursionLevel >= source.length) {
    dest.push(tempArr);
    return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= source[recursionLevel]; i++) {
    var tempArr2 = tempArr.slice(); // Copy tempArr
    tempArr2.push(i);
    fillArray(source, dest, recursionLevel + 1, tempArr2);
  }
}

fillArray(a, b, 0, []);
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the answer. Although I don't quite understand the construction principle of the method. Why should we pass both A and B there, instead of having B being returned? What is the recursionLevel and why a user should input as a parameter? Why can't the forth argument be [] by default? Thanks!

Comment: @Krishal You shouldn't pass the arrays `a` and `b` as parameters, but doing this do the function reusable. The `recursionLevel` parameter indicate the number of times this function called itself (for example, 0 in the first iteration, 1 in the next, and so forth. Note, all iteration this function called recursively number of times (the `for` loop) with **the same** `recursionLevel`. But this `recursionLevel` will be greater in one than of the called function). _Continue in the next comment_

Comment: _Continue from the previous comment_ The empty array passed in the first call, is a temp array that the function uses. You can create a helper function, like `function fillArrHelper(source, dest) { fillArray(source, dest, 0, []); },` and use it like `fillArrHelper(a, b);`.